# Counting documents in MongoDB collection using PHPs new MongoDB driver?

Tags: php, mongodb

Could someone please give me an example of how to count the number of documents in a MongoDB collection using PHPs new driver (http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

All examples seem to be either using the old driver or a library!

Answer (score 0):

The library is providing high level API for the driver so the best will be to take a look [how it's done there](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Operation/Count.php#L128). Generally speaking new driver is a thin layer that is meant to be low level so you shouldn't expect any sugar in it.